# controlling queue size in rabbitMQ when using celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I can see the queue of reserved tasks in celery by:

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
len(inspect().reserved().values()[0])
```

However, this queue seems to be small, (around 8-10) even when I send a 600 jobs to celery.

in shell, I can see there are 520 jobs waiting to enter the workers reserved queue in celery

```
>> sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues
Listing queues ...
ae20060e09ee49e3bf534141bb0ef921    1
63f1c530ce114f00b9d0ab595eb65c55    1
382e86abce8449e48b0b168fbcf4aebc    1
celeryev.68becb00-9f8f-4252-ab3a-2cd5c12890f6   0
celery  520
0988376d422a4e338bf2d32037c996fc    1
c401d93d38944caa967a147540c4a738    1
d1a78e47d28941749f65282652d973ff    1
ip-10-196-155-73.celery.pidbox  0
84b4d109f44c4e8ba5b549399cc53b30    1
5780425d-d2c7-3036-8be1-4298a51250ff.reply.celery.pidbox    0
8d0c1cd14ebb4fa2b25b565d409580dd    1
a44f22cf759c4e7dbb6fccd673ce1b62    1
77c17e95689740b68d9ca84b3065a2ce    1
```

However, I want to be able to know the queue current (520) and maximum capacity from python.

Alternatively, is rabbitMQ blocking once I fill the queue? if so, how do I find out the maximal capacity, and how can I change it?

Also, how can I know how many tasks remain in the queue?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you're asking here, are you saying you want to get the number of messages in a queue from Python?

Comment: yes, i want to know how i can get the number of messages in the queue, from python.
Also, how can I purge all messages in the queue from python.
Last, how can i know (or set) what is the maximum number of messages in the queue? which I expect will be in some config file, and not through python.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. It looks like you're confusing message prefetch with queue capacity or something like that. RabbitMQ has no limit on queue sizes but the physical limit imposed by the hardware itself.

Comment: eran: To explain what's been said so far: To increase performance, workers prefetch tasks before their child processes are ready for them (how many such tasks depends on CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER). Tasks that have been prefetched are considered "reserved", but not "active". celery's "inspect().reserved()" shows only these, not the ones still in the queue (inspect works by broadcasting a query to the workers, which _can't_ know about tasks they haven't fetched). Now you should clarify your question to "How can I know how many tasks remain in the queue?" (the answer to which I'd also like).